# Windows Phone: Call an Async method in OnNavigatedTo

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my WP8 app, I want to call an Async method when the page is navigated to.

I thought about marking the **OnNavigatedTo** method with **async** keyword to be like this:

```
async protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            await myAsyncMethod();
        }
```

is there a better approach to achieve this, is there a problem in labeling **OnNavigatedTo** with async ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope this is exactly what you should be doing. Mark OnNavigatedTo as async and then execute whatever you need to execute.

Comment: But what if the myAsyncMethod() takes a long time to execute, wouldn't that be a problem ?

Comment: the way async works is that it suspends current execution while async is being processed. async task is a very handy mechanism unfortunately you have to try it to get to grips with it.