# A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, deadlock

My situation: I'm logging into my app. After the login, chats will be loaded (it's a chat app). I'm trying to use `DataWriter.StoreAsync`, but it will always throw this exception:

> A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8000000E)

I've read a lot about async code in the past days and I'm struggling a lot with this exception. What I (believe to) know:

- I need to use `await` every time I'm running async code, otherwise my code won't wait for the return and throw exceptions
- I need to avoid `async void` because it won't return (only exception: events)
- I need to dispose a `DataWriter` after I used it to make sure that there won't be multiple threads using the same `DataWriter`

Unfortunately my code still throws the exception stated above. Maybe I forgot something or understood something about `async` wrong.

Since I'm working with server, it's not possible for me to provide a sample project. Sorry! Wall of code incoming now, sorry about that but my mistake could be anywhere in this code. The code is sorted by when it's executed from top to bottom:

---

Instance of `LoginCommand` in `MainPageViewModel`:

```
LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand(Login);
```

My `Login` method:

```
private async void Login()
{
    _evaLogger.Info("Trying to log in (online)...");
    await LoginOnline();
    _evaLogger.Info("Logged in (online)!!!");
}
```

The method is `async void` instead of `async Task` because `DelegateCommand` doesn't allow a `Task` and `DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler` is obsolete. But besides that, I've tried `DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler` and it didn't solve the issue.

`LoginOnline()`:

```
private async Task LoginOnline()
{
    // ... Other code ...
    await _websocketManager.connect(_accountInformation.GetToken(), _eventAggregator, _evaLogger, _dependencyService);
}
```

The `_websocketManager.connect()` method for my UWP implementation is this:

```
public async Task connect(string token, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, EvaLogger evaLogger, IDependencyService dependencyService)
{
    try
    {
        messageWebsocket.SetRequestHeader("iPlanetDirectoryPro", token);
        DependencyService = dependencyService;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _evaLogger = evaLogger;
        _localDataManager = new SqliteLocalDataManager(_evaLogger, _eventAggregator, dependencyService);
        messageWebsocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;
        messageWebsocket.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
        messageWebsocket.Closed += OnClosed;
        messageWebsocket.ServerCustomValidationRequested += OnOpened;

        _evaLogger.Info("WebsocketManager.Connect();");

        await messageWebsocket.ConnectAsync(WSURI); // This triggers the OnOpened event
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _evaLogger.Error(e.Message, e);
    }
}
```

Then the OnOpened event is triggered, which calls the `OnOpened` method. After some other code which isn't relevant for this exception and after a navigation which works fine, the `async void OnNavigatedTo` method is called. According to [this SO question], using async void here is fine:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064469/windows-phone-call-an-async-method-in-onnavigatedto)

```
public async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    await LoadDataTaskAsync();
}
```

`LoadDataTaskAsync` method:

```
private async Task LoadDataTaskAsync()
{
    // ... Other code ...
    _evaLogger.Info("LoadDataTaskAsync()");
    await _remoteDataManager.requestChats();
}

public async Task requestChats()
{
    await _websocketManager.requestChats(); // Gets the requestChats implementation for the current platform (in my case UWP)
}
```

`requestChats():`

```
public async Task requestChats()
{
        using (DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(messageWebsocket.OutputStream))
        {
            _evaLogger.Info("dataWriter initialized requestChats.");
            dataWriter.WriteString(WebsocketRequestFactory.Create(SocketEventsEnm.GET_CHATS));
            await SendData(dataWriter, "requestChats");
        }
    _evaLogger.Info("dataWriter disposed requestChats.");
}
```

And finally, `SendData()`:

```
private async Task SendData(DataWriter dataWriter, string method)
{
    try
    {
        _evaLogger.Info("Trying to send data... " + method);
        await dataWriter.StoreAsync(); // Exception is thrown here!!!
        _evaLogger.Info("Data was sent." + method);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _evaLogger.Error(e.Message, e);
    }
}
```

---

This is how my logfile looks after I run the application:

> 14.12.2016 15:36:33 - Info: Trying to log in (online)...
>
> 14.12.2016 15:36:33 - Info: WebsocketManager.Connect();
>
> 14.12.2016 15:36:33 - Info: MessageWebSocket Opened
>
> 14.12.2016 15:36:33 - Info: LoadDataTaskAsync()
>
> 14.12.2016 15:36:33 - Info: dataWriter initialized requestChats.
>
> 14.12.2016 15:36:33 - Info: Trying to send data... requestChats
>
> 14.12.2016 15:36:33 - Error: A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)
>
> 14.12.2016 15:36:33 - Info: dataWriter disposed requestChats.
>
> 14.12.2016 15:36:34 - Info: Websocket Opened
>
> 14.12.2016 15:36:34 - Info: Logged in (online)!!!

The logfile looks (except for the exception) fine for me, everything is executed in the right order.

Again, sorry for the long code. But I think it could be everywhere in this code and I removed every unnecessary line of code which doesn't cause the exception for sure (this is why it might seem weird why I have so many methods).

### EDIT:

After removing the `OnOpened` event, it's working *most of the times*. But I'm still getting the same exception occasionally.

This is the stacktrace:

```
Error: A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)
   at Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter.StoreAsync()
   at One.UWP.Websockets.WebsocketManager.<SendData>d__30.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Have you tried simply moving the `dataWriter.StoreAsync();` into your `requestChats()` method? What I mean is, it looks like it was needlessly moved into another function. Does it need to be like that?

Comment: @gmiley I tried it an this changes something... I won't get the exception anymore, but my app just crashes without any exception. Originally I implemented `SendData` because I have many other methods which also need the `dataWriter.StoreAsync()` method, but I could drop it if that would fix the issue

Comment: You may need to do some more analysis on your program flow. Are you doing unit tests with your development to test all code paths?

Comment: Also, when you moved that call, did you wrap it in a try/catch to output the error or is it just getting swallowed up now. You may still be getting the same error. I just wanted to see if there was some other issues with async/await that you might be running into.

Comment: @gmiley ah my mistake, how stupid. With try/catch it's the same, still the exception. No I do not have unit tests but unfortunately I can't put in time into that at the moment

Comment: @gmiley After removing the `OnOpened` event, it's working. But every ~5th time I'm logging into my app, I will get the exception again and I have to restart the app.

Comment: Can you trace to where exactly the exception is being thrown? And is it every 5 times exactly, or is it occasionally 4 or 6?

Comment: @gmiley Occasionally... I've edited my question with the stacktrace at the bottom of the question!

Comment: Is it now another method that is calling `SendData`? You said that you moved the `StoreAsync` call into `requestChats`, but that you had other places that `SendData` was called from. It looks like the error is still occurring within `SendData` so try doing the same thing with the other calls to `SendData` and replace it with a direct `StoreAsync` call instead of calling out to that `SendData` function.